# Choice of composite number is a proof about n being prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

The following is a proof (from a deleted post) for the following:

*Let $n \geq 2$ be an integer. Suppose that $n$ divides ${n}\choose{k}$ for all $0<k<n$. Prove that $n$ is prime.*

**Proof**

Suppose $n$ is compositive, and written $n=kp$ for $p$ prime. Since $n$ divides ${n}\choose{p}$, we can write $an=$${n}\choose{p}$ for some integer $a$. So, we compute

$an=akp$=${n}\choose{p}$$= \frac{(kp)(kp-1)...(kp-p+1)}{p(p-1)...(2)(1)}$

and dividing both sides by n=kp, we get

$a=$$\frac{(kp-1)...(kp-p+1)}{p(p-1)...(2)(1)}$

which is a contradiction since the numerator on the RHS is not divisible by $p$ and the denominator is, so the fraction cannot reduce to an integer.

**QED**

My question is the choice of $n=kp$. How and why is it the same $p$ in ${n}\choose{k}$. It seems like they aren't necessarily the same? What does $n$ being prime have to do with this?

Comment: Please do not delete a question immediately after getting an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to  answer your question, and to future readers who might benefit from the answer.  This also deprives the community of the opportunity to make its own decision about whether or not the question is useful for the site.

Answer (score 2):

- The usage of $k$ is unlucky. The $k$ in $n=kp$ actually has nothing to do with the $k$ in $0<k<n$.
- If $n$ is composite , then it has a prime factor $p$ , so we can write $n=mp$ for some positive integer $m$. Since $n$ is composite , we also have $0<p<n$ which we need to arrive at a contradiction. The proof basically shows $n\nmid \binom{n}{p}$ , so the proof by contradiction is complete.
- As a bonus , we also have that the converse is true , namely that for $n$ prime we have $n\mid \binom{n}{m}$ for every $m$ with $0<m<n$. This is because in

$$\frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-m+1)}{m(m-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1}$$ the denominator is not divisible by $n$ because of $m<n$ , but the numerator is divisible by $n$. Hence , the binomial coefficient must be divisible by $n$.